# All Content loading expect photos on IIS 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, windows-server-2019

I have a problem that my application works fine on local environment (all functionality
include photos, but when I run app on IIS 10 all functions worked expect add Photos (return 500 Internal Server Error), and List photos  (404 Not Found).But I said before photo functionality works (Adding/Listing) on Local Server

App made on ASP.NET CORE 5.0

Any suggestions ?

Comment: First, I think we can use ip:port/folder to see the photos deployed to iis according the file folder you deployed. And let's see the network information in browser's console panel(f12) to see more details about 404. And I think you can also share some code snippets on this case to help locate the issue, I mean the code about list photos and add photos, especially relating to setting file path.

Comment: Enable FRT and see what's actually happening under the hood, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Answer (score 1):

The problem was , I forget give permission to folder which contains photos,Thank you for answers